# Recommended serialization library for dynamically sized objects

Tags: borsh, deserialization, serialization

I am trying to write a vector of objects into a solana account. The problem is, the pre-allocated size of the account might be too small for my vector. I know i can re-size the account with `realloc`, but I still don't know the *serialized* size of my vector of objects, which I need to call realloc.

I could implement my own serialization logic, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Are there any serialization libraries out there that tell you the size of the serialized object *before* you serialize it?

Comment: I took a quick look at borsh and bincode and I don't think they satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Borsh is fine and I've used it for variable size objects (like `vec`). However; if you are trying to manage a large vector or it's growth can potentially be large you may want to consider using PDA for whatever info you would store in the `vec`. Any serialization is going to consume more CU and that may be prohibitive.

Comment: Can you add more context to your question? What are you storing in the vector, how often will it grow? What is the general use case?

Comment: I have a struct called Obligation, which manages a user's deposits and borrows. The amount of deposits and borrows is dynamic. Currently, we have the size hardcoded so the amount of deposits and borrows can't exceed 10. I would like to remove this constraint, especially since re-alloc lets us do dynamic resizing.

Comment: see: https://github.com/solendprotocol/solana-program-library/blob/mainnet/token-lending/program/src/state/obligation.rs#L35

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't want to serialize an account within the runtime. For any meaningfully sized account, this will use up more compute units than you have. I have generally gotten away with just looking up the byte length of the account after all state changes have been made and then calling realloc with that value.

```
let data_len = my_account.try_to_vec()?.len();
my_account.to_account_info().realloc(data_len, false)?;
```

Comment: ok interesting...im surprised that works. i kinda assumed you wouldn't even be able to make length-increasing state changes without calling realloc first. Time to dig into source code lol

Comment: Will mark as correct when i verify this :)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/1ea6a2cb91288d7f08ee130025a2aad6dce9b60d/sdk/src/account.rs#L98) seems to be how the Account is stored on chain. Since it is a vector, I think your answer works! Thanks